# website display issue - Elements in menu-bar not showing when they have sub-menus

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, menubar

I developed a website and recognized an error during the cross browser testing.

In Internet Explorer 11 elements in my menu-bar are not shown when they have sub-menus.

Here is an image to show the error:

[image: the menu-bar in ie11]

In the Edge Browser things are a little bit more tricky. The sub-menu elements are shown in the first place. But when one hovers over the element, so that the sub-menu item list appears and then hover over an element which contains a sub-sub-menu, every menu item with a sub-menu disappears in the menu-bar.

Here is an image from Edge:

[image: the menu-bar in Edge]

The link to my testpage is http://undefined.bplaced.net

The menu-bar works well in every other browser I tested (latest version of FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Andriod, iPhone), just the Microsoft browsers are '*special*'.

I'm not sure where/how to search for that error, maybe it's caused by the CSS (I prefixed my CSS for IE/Edge) or jQuery/JavaScript or maybe it's even the ul li HTML markup, I don't know.

here is the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript I applied to the menu:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // add JS-classes into the HTML-Tag
  $('html').addClass('js');

  // add classes for sub menus and sub menus toggle button
  $(".site-nav li > ul").parent('li').addClass('has-sub-menu');
  $(".site-nav li > ul").addClass('sub-menu');

  // create button for expand- und collapse the menu and render it into the header
  var create_toggle_nav_button = ['<div class="toggle-site-nav">Menu</div>'].join("");
  $("header").append(create_toggle_nav_button);

  // create button for expand- und collapse the sub menu  for mobile view and add them to all sub menus
  var create_sub_toggle_button = ['<span class="toggle-sub-menu"></span>'].join("");
  $(".has-sub-menu > a").after(create_sub_toggle_button);

  // define variables
  var $menu = $('.site-nav'),
    $toggle_nav = $('.toggle-site-nav'),
    $toggle_sub_menu = $('.toggle-sub-menu');

  // collapse and expand function of the main menu
  $toggle_nav.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $menu.slideToggle();
  });

  // collapse and expand function of the drop down menu for mobile view
  $toggle_sub_menu.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').slideToggle();
  });

  // display hidden elements again, when browserwindow is resized by user
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w > 900) {
      $('.site-nav').removeAttr('style');
      $('.sub-menu').removeAttr('style');
    }
  });

  // collapse navigation automatically to the left, when it run out of the viewport
  $(".site-nav .has-sub-menu").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {

    var nav_element = $('ul:first', this);
    var element_offset = nav_element.offset();
    var element_offset_left = element_offset.left;
    var element_width = nav_element.width();
    var viewport_width = $(window).width();

    var element_in_viewport = (element_offset_left + element_width <= viewport_width);

    if (!element_in_viewport) {
      $(this).addClass('sub-left');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('sub-left');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  z-index: 10;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  /* ? */
}

.site-nav {
  z-index: 10;
}

.site-nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
}

.site-nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.site-nav a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  padding: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  /* text color of all */
  background: #5a595a;
  /* background color main nav Link 1 */
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 10;
}

.site-nav a:hover {
  background: #8c8e94;
  /* mouseover color Link 1 and Link 1.1 opacity */
}

.js .site-nav {
  display: none;
}

.js .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 12;
}

.js .sub-menu .sub-menu {
  top: 0px;
  right: 100%;
  left: auto;
  text-align: right;
}

.js .has-sub-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
}

.sub-menu li:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.sub-menu a {
  background: #676567;
  /* background color menu 2.1 only */
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu a {
  background: #747274;
  /* background color menu 2.1.1 only */
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu a:hover {
  background: #8c8e94;
  /* mouseover color Link 1 and Link 1.1 */
}


/* toggles */

.toggle-site-nav {
  background: #5a595a;
  /* background color of menu button when resized */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  /* text color of the word menu in menu button when resized */
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}

.toggle-site-nav:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* mouseover color of menu button when resized */
}

.toggle-sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.js .toggle-sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  align-content: center;
  right: 0em;
  top: 1.05em;
  /* hight of the borders */
  background: #817e81;
  /* backgound of annoying squares when resized */
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 11;
}

.js .toggle-sub-menu.active {
  background: #DCDCDC;
  /* color of annoying square after clicking on it when resized */
}

.toggle-sub-menu:hover,
.toggle-sub-menu.active:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* mouseover of annoying squares when resized */
}

@media screen and (min-width:900px) {
  .logo {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
  }
  .site-nav {
    width: auto;
    display: flex !important;
  }
  .site-nav a {
    border: none;
  }
  .site-nav li {
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .site-nav li:hover {
    background: rgba(52, 50, 52, 1);
    /* mouseover background color of all menu */
  }
  .has-sub-menu a {
    padding-right: 2em;
    /* check this value */
  }
  .has-sub-menu:after {
    /* check this for editing the stripes */
    display: block;
    content: '';
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background: url(http://undefined.bplaced.net/ic_expand_more_18px.svg);
    background-size: 18px 18px;
    position: absolute;
    align-content: center;
    top: 1.0em;
    right: 0.5em;
  }
  /* sub menu */
  .site-nav li:hover>.sub-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    /* width of sub menus */
    padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
    left: -25px;
  }
  .sub-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .sub-menu li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sub-menu>a {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  .has-sub-menu .has-sub-menu:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background: url(http://undefined.bplaced.net/ic_chevron_right_18px.svg);
    background-size: 18px 18px;
    position: absolute;
    align-content: center;
    top: 1.0em;
    right: 0.5em;
  }
  .has-sub-menu .has-sub-menu:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    /* width of subsub menues */
    padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
    left: 224px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .toggle-site-nav,
  .toggle-sub-menu {
    display: none !important;
  }
  /* navigations items, which collapse to the left */
  .sub-left>.sub-menu {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
  }
  .site-nav .sub-menu .sub-left>.sub-menu {
    left: -275px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 899px) {
  .site-nav>ul {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .site-nav>ul>li {
    display: block !important;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .site-nav {
    z-index: 13;
    margin-top: 19px;
  }
  .js .toggle-sub-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    align-content: center;
    right: 0.3em;
    top: 0.29em;
    /* hight of the borders */
    background: #817e81;
    /* backgound of annoying squares when resized */
    width: 2.7em;
    height: 2.7em;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 11;
  }
  .toggle-sub-menu:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    background: url(http://undefined.bplaced.net/ic_expand_more_36px_wt.svg);
    background-size: 36px 36px;
    position: absolute;
    align-content: center;
    top: 0.2em;
    left: 0.1118em;
  }
  .js .toggle-sub-menu.active {
    background: #141614;
    /* color of annoying square after clicking on it when resized */
  }
  .toggle-sub-menu:hover,
  .toggle-sub-menu.active:hover {
    background-color: #313431;
    /* mouseover of annoying squares when resized */
  }
  .sub-menu {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    /* width of sub menu */
  }
  .has-sub-menu {
    display: block !important;
    margin: auto !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    /* width of subsub menu */
  }
  /* sub menu */
  .has-sub-menu .has-sub-menu .sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /* width of subsub menues */
    margin: auto;
    left: 0px;
    top: auto;
    z-index: 99999;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <nav class="site-nav" id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="./about-us/index.html">about us</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="./about-us/test-new/index.html"><span>TEST new</span></a>
            <li><a href="./about-us/our-team/index.html"><span>our team</span></a>
              <li><a href="./about-us/quality/index.html"><span>quality</span></a>
                <li><a href="./about-us/our-offices/index.html"><span>our offices</span></a>
                  <li><a href="./about-us/catalog/index.html"><span>catalog</span></a>
                    <li><a href="./about-us/map/index.html"><span>map</span></a>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="./Products/index.html">Products</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="./Products/mainproducts_1/index.html"><span>mainproducts_1</span></a>
              <li><a href="./Products/mainproducts_2/index.html"><span>mainproducts_2</span></a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="./Products/mainproducts_2/xv/index.html"><span>xV</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="./Products/mainproducts_2/current/index.html"><span>current</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="./Products/mainproducts_3/index.html"><span>mainproducts_3</span></a>
                  <li><a href="./Products/mainproducts_4/index.html"><span>mainproducts_4</span></a>
                    <li><a href="./Products/mainproducts_5/index.html"><span>mainproducts_5</span></a>
                      <li><a href="./Products/mainproducts_6/index.html"><span>mainproducts_6</span></a>
                        <li><a href="./Products/mainproducts_7/index.html"><span>mainproducts_7</span></a>
                          <li><a href="./Products/mainproducts_8/index.html"><span>mainproducts_8</span></a>
                            <li><a href="./Products/mainproducts_9/index.html"><span>mainproducts_9</span></a>
                              <li><a href="./Products/mainproducts_10/index.html"><span>mainproducts_10</span></a>
                                <li><a href="./Products/mainproducts_11/index.html"><span>mainproducts_11</span></a>
          </ul>
          <li><a href="./testpage2/index.html">Testpage2</a>
            <li><a href="./testpage3/index.html">Testpage3</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="./testseite3/subpage2_1/index.html"><span>subpage2_1</span></a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="./testpage3/subpage2_1/subpage2_2/index.html"><span>subpage2_2</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="./testpage3/subpage2_1/subsubpage_3_1/index.html"><span>subsubpage_3_1</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <li><a href="./testpage3/test3_1/index.html"><span>Test3_1</span></a>
                    <li><a href="./testpage3/test4_1/index.html"><span>Test4_1</span></a>
              </ul>
              <li><a href="./testseite4/index.html">Testpage4</a>
                <li><a href="./testseite5/index.html">Testpage5</a>
                  <li><a href="./anfrage--kontakt/index.php">Contact</a>
                    <li><a href="./english/index.php">English</a>
                    </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Here is also a link to my pen: [pen menu-bar](https://codepen.io/undefined999/pen/KydpgX)

I would really appreciate any hint how to track down this bug.

Comment: `.js .has-sub-menu` sets `position:relative` and `top:100%` on those items, and that’s what makes them disappear in IE. Not sure what `top:100%` was supposed to achieve here in the first place, but without it, it looks fine (and does in Chrome as well.)

Comment: @CBroe thank you very much for your comment. I I removed the `top:100%`and it really solved the problem! How did you figure that out within all those dozens of code lines? Are you a wizard? Should be an answer and not comment

Comment: downvoters please explain why, to help me to improve

Comment: Not a wizard, no ... IE has dev tools, too, and using those to look at the issue this was the first thing that looked fishy ...

Comment: for sure I u sed the dev tools too and tried to find the error for like a week now. But it would have never come to mind that a simple top:100% would cause a problem like this. out of curiosity, do you know why it didnt affect Firefox as well? I upvoted your answer but it's not shown because that downvote pushed me back below 15 rep. Anyway, thank you very much

Comment: It wasn’t one look at the code and then “ah, that must be it”, but rather a little bit of trial&error (inspect element, disable certain properties, and see what the effect is.) Since the problem was elements not showing where they were supposed to, the position stuff just looked like a good place to start ... Dunno why it did not affect Firefox/Chrome the same way, that would need some more analysis of the whole thing I guess.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and help. I really appreciate and value that. Maybe I figure out one day why it did not affect Chrome and Firefox, I'll let you know if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule `.js .has-sub-menu` sets `position:relative; top:100%` on those items, and that’s what makes them disappear in IE.

Not sure what `top:100%` was supposed to achieve here in the first place, but without it, it looks fine (and does in Chrome as well), so I guess you can just completely remove that.